# Why register with Unity when instance is already mocked

Tags: unity-container, moq

I just came across some existing code from an existing application and I'm trying to understand the first two lines in the unit test. Here is the unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void CanDisplayReportWithPage()
    {
        var claimComponent = new Mock<IClaimsComponent>();
        GlobalContainer.Unity.RegisterInstance(claimComponent.Object);

        _pharmacyCdmService
            .Setup(service => service.ReadAllTenantEstablishments((It.IsAny<Guid>())))
            .Returns(ResponseHelper.CreateResponse(new TenantEstablishmentDataContract[0]));

        _pharmacyCdmService
            .Setup(service => service.ReadTenantById((It.IsAny<long>())))
            .Returns(ResponseHelper.CreateResponse(new TenantDataContract()));

        claimComponent.Setup(
            component => component.FileDetailsClaimReport(It.IsAny<RamqDetailsClaimReportRequestDataContract>()))
            .Returns(new RamqDetailsClaimReportResponseDataContract());

        var result = (ViewResult)_controller.View(new DetailsReportModel(), 3);

        _pharmacyCdmService.VerifyAll();
        _claimIdentityHelper.VerifyAll();

        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.IsNotNull(result.Model);
        Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.ViewName);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result.Model, typeof(DetailsReportModel));
        Assert.AreEqual(2, ((DetailsReportModel) result.Model).DataContract.PageTransaction);
    }
```

This test uses a combination of Moq and Unity. What I'm trying to understand is why the mocked instance (claimComponent) has to be registered with Unity.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is the system under test uses the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). GlobalContainer is the key - it's probably a Singleton (generally another anti-pattern) that makes the IoC container available everywhere.

A better alternative would be to use constructor injection (probably with the controller) using [Unity.MVC3](http://unitymvc3.codeplex.com/) or equivalent. That lets you compose everything in one [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). Your unit tests typically don't need to reference Unity at all; they can just create a mock and pass it to the controller.